# short way of producing array of randomly draw strings by RandomStringUtils

Tags: java, string, random

I would like to produce an array of randomly creating strings in a short way. There is such a way in case ints (instead of strings), so I'm searching for something similar using `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils` instead of `java.util.Random`.

I've tried to search through methods for RandomStringUtils, but I didn't found anything useful.

The simple code producing an array of 13 pieces of ints is as follows:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
int[] toReturn = r.ints(0,100).limit(13).toArray();
```

Is it possible to find something analogous for `RandomStringUtils`?

Comment: All the methods of RandomStringUtils create **one** random string. If you want an **array** of random strings, just create an array, use a loop, and call the method you want to generate every elementof the array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 2):

`RandomStringUtils` doesn't have streaming methods, but you could use `IntStream` to create a stream and then just map it to some random string generation. E.g.:

```
int len = 10;
int numStrings = 13;
String[] randomStrings =
    IntStream.range(0, len).mapToObj(i -> RandomStringUtils.random(len)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work, it says: "Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.String[] Found: java.lang.Object[]". I can't fix it, could you help?

Comment: @Almostsure sorry, I forgot the init function. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Mureinik, sorry, but it is still wrong. "new" at the end of the toArray() content?

Comment: @Almostsure I had a single `:` instead of a double `::` - it's indeed a `new` - it's a reference to a String array constructor.